# rsync: Ignore multiple extensions

Tags: rsync

My aim is to just sync all newer files from a source to my destinatino. I ran into multiple file extensions that I want to exclude. Do I have to specify multiple '--exclude' arguments or can I combine them?

```
rsync @source @dest --mode=rutzv --ignore-existing --exclude=*.msi --exclude=*.mp3
```